# Problem regarding displaying decimal values in C Program

Tags: c

the data-type 'float' displays decimal numbers. by default my compiler displays up-to 6 decimals. i want to see only two decimals. for eg , when the compiler performs the operation "c=2/3"
it displays "0.666666667". i want to see only "0.67" in my output screen.
so what necessary changes should i make in the C program?

Comment: Thank You for all the efforts everyone.Apreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a format specifier to limit it to 2 decimal places when outputting the number using `printf`.

```
int main() {
  double d = 2.0 / 3.0;
  printf("%.2f\n",d);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
---------- Capture Output ----------
> "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c c:\temp\temp.exe
0.67

> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell us how you display the value at all, therefore I guess you’re using something like `printf("%f", x)`. You can prefix the “f” with a precision specification, which is a dot followed by a number, for example `printf("%.2f", x)`.

Answer (score 1):

The printf formatting for decimals is %. followed by the amount of decimal precision displayed followed by "f".

So displaying two decimal placess would be

```
printf("%.2f", i);
```

and displaying six decimal places would be

```
printf("%.6f", i);
```