# C swapping elements in two dimensional array

Tags: c, function, swap

I wrote swap function in C.

```
void swapping(int dim, int size, void *n1, void *n2) {
   int s = dim * size;
   char a[s];
   memcpy(a, n2, s);
   memcpy(n2, n1, s);
   memcpy(n1, a, s);
}
```

I have let's say:

```
double t[10][3];
// write some value to array
```

when I swapping two elements:

```
swapping(3, sizeof(double), &t[1], &t[2]);
```

and `printf` them on the console. I got correct value not on every place.
For example: with

```
t[1][3] = { 123.0000, 324.1231, 923.9992};
```

I got:

```
123.0000120, 324.1231029, 923.999350
```

Where is the problem?

P.S. I used `void *` because I want to use this function with different types.

Comment: Your problem is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462863/problem-regarding-displaying-decimal-values-in-c-program)

Comment: Your code is unclear. What is `t[1][3] = { 123.0000, 324.1231, 923.9992};` an assignment, initialization. This is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Some beforehand thoughts*

First, you can't assign so values to arrays, that works only when you initialize them. So,

```
t[1][3] = { 123.0000, 324.1231, 923.9992};
```

is **compilation error**. You must assign them one by one (e.g. in a loop)

```
t[1][0] = 123.0000;
t[1][1] = 324.1231;
t[1][2] = 923.9992;
```

*Your problem*

Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/bvXTSb) to *ideone*-compiler, so that you can observe a different end-result. Basically, it prints:

```
t2: 123.000000
t2: 324.123100
t2: 923.999200
```

You get the last two after-comma digits to be crap, because of the way your OS manages free space. It actually doesn't delete or really *free* it, it just marks it as `free` or *writable*, because that way it is more efficient (no unnecessary operations), easy to implement (linked-list), and lastly, it enables file recovery without extra disk writes.

That's why you get most probably something different from `00`'s. Also that comes from the default representation of floats/doubles in C.

> For a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be printed after the decimal point (by default, this is 6).

*Solution*

Restrict the precision to the first 4 after-comma digits by

```
printf("t2: %.4f\n", t[2][i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
printf("%.4f\n",d);
```

Your problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462863/problem-regarding-displaying-decimal-values-in-c-program) I think.

For testing it.
If you just write a program to scan a number and print the same number. Then enter `333.33333` at the time of scan. It will give you output as `333.333344`

Comment: But my swap fuction is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `swapping(3, sizeof(double), t[1], t[2]);` instead of `swapping(3, sizeof(double), &t[1], &t[2]);` ?

Indeed, `t[1]` is a `double*`, that is a pointer to the second row. This is exactly what the function `swap` needs.

Sample code, based on yours:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swapping(int dim, int size, void* n1, void *n2)
{
    int s = dim * size;
    char a[s];
    memcpy(a, n2, s);
    memcpy(n2, n1, s);
    memcpy(n1, a, s);
}

int main(void) {

    int i,j;
    double t[10][3];

    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            t[j][i]=j+0.04665387*i;
        }
    }
    t[1][0]=123.0000;
    t[1][1]=324.1231;
    t[1][2]=923.9992;

    // write some value to array

    swapping(3, sizeof(double), t[1], t[2]);

    for(j=0;j<10;j++){
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            printf("%.10lg ",t[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `gcc main.c -o main -Wall`

Answer (score 0):

Your `swapping` function seems correct for reasonable array sizes.

You did not post the code you use to print the array contents, posting a complete compilable example would let us see what goes wrong.  If you use a different format for the first and second printout, or use an intermediary `float` variable, you could observe this problem.

Comment: I think your assessment is correct. The question is unanswerable. Therefore instead of an answer (that really isn't one), may I suggest a close vote?